# Jquery each and attr

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, each

I have some external links in my page

```
<a href="http://example.com/link-1" class="ext">Label</a>
<a href="http://example.com/link-2" class="ext">Label</a>
```

I try to direct the `ext` link to an exit page before automatically redirecting it to the destination. It works fine, but with multiple `ext` links on the page, my script is getting the `href` of `link-1` for other `ext` links too.

Ergo:

```
// To grab the href of the destination page i.e http://example.com/link-1
var external = $(".ext").attr('href');

// To forward to the exit page first i.e http://localhost/checkLinkURL?=http://example.com/link-1
$(".ext").attr('href', 'http://localhost/checkLinkURL?=' + external);
```

I have tried wrapping the second part of code in an `each` function but it still gets only the `href` of `link-1`. I don't know if the rest of my script is relevant to the problem. It's pretty basic and just strips out the exit page and forwards automatically to the destination. But how come this doesn't work as intended, even with an `each` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `href` attribute of each link, you can use [`.attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) with a callback function which provides the current `href` for you as the second argument, which you can use as your query string:

```js
$('.ext').attr('href', function(i, external) {
  return 'http://localhost/checkLinkURL?=' + external;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://example.com/link-1" class="ext">Label</a>
<a href="http://example.com/link-2" class="ext">Label</a>
```

Comment: You don't need to `.each()`. The `.attr()` also iterate elements. `$('.ext').attr(...`